# Instantiating ViewModel for a View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, view, viewmodel

**Update** Binding hidden fields of a viewmodel.

Let me try to explain my situation. I may be completely wrong but this is what I believe causing issue to me.

I have a ViewModel
**Project Create View Model**

```
[Bind(Exclude="List")]
    public class ProjectCreateViewModel : ProjectViewModelBase
    {
        public CourseViewModelBase CourseVM { get; set; }

        public ProjectCreateViewModel()
            : base()
        {
            this.CourseVM = new CourseViewModelBase();
        }    
    }
```

**Project View Model Base** is the base viewModel for a project and all associated actions derive from this so that I don't need to write property names again and again.

**Create View Model Base** is similar to ProjectViewModelBase(handled or used by ProjectController) but for a course (handled by CourseController).

Now I've created a form for *"Create New Project"* which uses *ProjectCreateViewModel*. In Form post action however **CourseVM** is always **null**.

**Create New Project .cshtml**

```
@model LMSPriorTool.ViewModels.ProjectCreateViewModel

@* --- labels and other stuff -- *@
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateNewProject", "Project", 
                       FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", 
                       name = "createNewProjectForm" }))
{
     <!-- Hidden Fields -->
     @Html.HiddenFor( x => x.ProjectId)
     @Html.HiddenFor( x => x.CourseVM)   // CourseVM is null in post action
     @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.CourseVM.CourseNumberRoot)    // This is displayed properly                             
}
```

**ProjectController**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CreateNewProject(CourseViewModelBase courseVM = null)
{
      ProjectCreateViewModel projectCreateViewModel = new ProjectCreateViewModel
      {
           CourseVM = courseVM,
      };

      // OTHER STUFF

      return View("CreateNewProject", projectCreateViewModel);
}
```

**Error**
In HTTPPOST action I'm getting CourseVM as null, though I have provided it as a hidden field in form.

[image]

**<strike>Possible Issue</strike>** I belive issue is with the Constructor of **ProjectCreateViewModel** as when HTTPPOST action occur, view will try to create new instance of **ProjectCreateViewModel** and instantiate the CourseVM as null. Then same instance is passed to the HTTPPOST method in which CourseVM is appearing as null.

**UPDATE: ISSUE ROOT CAUSE** Complex objects cannot be bind to a viewmodel using Hidden Fields.

Any suggestions or thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need that `HiddenFor` of `CourseVM`. MVC will create the class automatically for you because you are binding `CourseVM.CourseNumberRoot`

At the moment, you are attempting to bind `CourseVM`, which is a complex object, from a hidden input which MVC can't do, so it is returning null.

Comment: and That worked perfectly. I thought putting the whole "CourseVM" as hidden will create new courseVM object. Thanks for the information about "Complex Object cannot be binded to hidden inputs fields"